# Installing a .bundle file in Fedora linux

Tags: linux, vmware, fedora

So I am using Ozone OS which is basically just fedora with a cool theme, and a lot less crap installed. I tried installing VMWare Horizon view client from here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VIEWCLIENTS_LINUX_32&productId=421&rPId=7320

and then i renamed the file to vmware.bundle, when i make it runnable with:

```
chmod +x vmware.bundle
```

i ran the file using:

```
./vmware.bundle
```

this is what happens in my terminal

```
VMWare Horizon Client is an x86 application but you are trying to install it to an x64 Linux.
To run this installation, you may need to install 32-bit runtime libraries. Do you want to proceed? (yes/no)yes
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
```

but when i try going to the application menu, I can find VMware anywhere

Answer (score 0):

There is really no such thing as ".bundle" files on Fedora. The only format for installable software on Fedora are RPM files.

All that this ".bundle" file appears to be, is the vendor's custom installation script, that's all. It's not any kind of a standard packaging format, of any kind.

You will be able to find a newly-installed application on your application menu only if the application correctly installed a `.desktop` file in the right location. If this installation script did not do so, you won't get anything in the application menu.

It is the application script's responsibility to install a `.desktop` file in order for the application to appear in the application menu.

Answer (score 0):

try running /bin/vmware
that is the default install location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).